# Except an error in Python from a loaded C library

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I have this piece of code which loads a library, but then it dies. I've surrounded it with the try/except pass, but it still dies. Does anyone know how to get past the error and continue with the print statement below:

```
      try: 
         library.load("test_data/polo.lib")
      except:
         pass

     defines = library.get_defines()
     print defines
     assert ( len(defines) == 3), "Make sure we have 3 defines"
```

The error I get right after the library.load line of code is:

```
scci18910> python test_001_library.py
Loading library test_data/polo.lib   
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::string'
Abort
```

Comment: You need to be clearer about what `library.load` does. How that code loads/wraps the C library polo.lib with Python is crucial to how the error should be caught.

Comment: I think "test_data/polo.lib" is doing exit of application forcefully thats why try , except is not working . You need to look into this library to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You cant catch exception, because no python exception is thrown.
But you can use subprocess to bypass `Abort`:

create file `list_defines.py`:

```
library.load("test_data/polo.lib")
print(library.get_defines())
```

then:

```
import subprocess

try:
    defines = parse_string_to_list_somehow(subprocess.check_output('python', '-c', 'list_defines.py'))
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print('Library defines list failed', e)
    defines = []
```

P.S. Example is for python3

Comment: Why bother with a Python wrapper to a c-library at all if you're going to wrap the Python wrapper in a subprocess call! Why not just subprocess call some c-program. This might work, but it cannot be the canonical solution to this problem.

Comment: Possibly youre right, but we dont know deployment requirements.

Comment: Thanks, Denz! I'm working in Python 2.7 though. What might be the equivalent?